# Height of anchor with an image iside has more height that the rest of the elements

Tags: html, css

I'm building a navbar with text and icons whit a change in the background color with hoover, but I have a problem with the height of the icons' background. I want them to have the same height as the text but I don't know why they have a bigger background.

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7coA.png)

As you can see there is a small difference between the background of icons and the background of text. I found a solution that is adding a negative bottom margin to the icons but that way the icons are not centered. Another possible solution is to add a height to the anchors but in that case the text is not centered. I don't understand that small space, the anchor doesn't adjust itself to the image as it does with the text and I don't know why. Do you know a better way to fix this?

This is the HTML and CSS code for my navbar:

```css
nav
{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul
{
  background-color: #343A40;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav li
{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right
{
  float: right;
}


ul.topnav li a
{
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-height: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a.active
{
  background-color: #00B5FF;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover
{
  background-color: #00B5FF;
}

ul.topnav li a img.icon
{
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html"><img class="icon" src="images/home.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li><a href="acerca.html">Acerca</a></li>
        <li><a href="portafolio.html">Portafolio</a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://github.com/BernardoAyala"><img class="icon" src="images/github.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bernardo-ayala-94630216a/"><img class="icon" src="images/linkedin.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/bernardoayalam/"><img class="icon" src="images/instagram.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://twitter.com/Bernardo_Ayala"><img class="icon" src="images/twitter.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: remove `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Oh I wrote that trying to fix the problem but it didn't work, I've already deleted it and nothing changed. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was. Pay atention to this part of my CSS:

```css
ul.topnav li a
{
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-height: 17px;
}
```

Notice that mi anchors inside that list have a padding of 16px, that padding was the extra space that I didn't know where it came from. To solve this I added a class to that specific anchor an I change its the padding.

Answer (score 0):

The image is what is causing your Nav bar to be longer than it should be. One simple way you can do is to specify a height for your nav bar when hovered to be the same as your un-hovered nav bar.

```css
nav
{
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul
{
  background-color: #343A40;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav li
{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li.topnav-right
{
  float: right;
}


ul.topnav li a
{
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  min-height: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a.active
{
  background-color: #00B5FF;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover
{
  background-color: #00B5FF;
  height:20px;
}

ul.topnav li a img.icon
{
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html"><img class="icon" src="images/home.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li><a href="acerca.html">Acerca</a></li>
        <li><a href="portafolio.html">Portafolio</a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://github.com/BernardoAyala"><img class="icon" src="images/github.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bernardo-ayala-94630216a/"><img class="icon" src="images/linkedin.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/bernardoayalam/"><img class="icon" src="images/instagram.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
        <li class="topnav-right"><a href="https://twitter.com/Bernardo_Ayala"><img class="icon" src="images/twitter.png" alt="icon"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: That's a good solution, but in that case the navbar is bigger than the hover so the background doesn't fit the height of the bar. This is how it looks like: 
https://imgur.com/a/lwJ9qpf